# What is the safest way to store a 2 way password?

Tags: mysql, sql, security, passwords, password-protection

I want to create a password store for use within our local area network,
the password store is going to be something similar to keypass but with user access levels.

The reason I want to make something like this is that having a password file available for potentially malicious users doesn't seem like a good idea.

Should I encrypt this database two way and only give the key to the running application, or is it just better to secure the machine itself and just store in plain-text (which sounds bad, if it were a publicly available website)

They main issue there is that the password have to be retrieved to access the server of some clients that refuse to use keys and theirs passwords will have to be stored confidentially.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two-way encryption is certainly better than nothing.  It may not be perfect, but it creates one more barrier to accessing the passwords.

You could also use this system only for clients who refuse to implement good security.  Use an optimal system (and different passwords, obviously) for the rest.  That way the potential damage is limited to those clients only.